# Is there a canonical way to allow implicit conversion of a non-const template argument type to a const one?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a function that takes arguments of a specific template type; a simplified version might look like:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct foo
{
    // default constructor
    foo() { }

    // simple copy constructor that can construct a foo<T> from a foo<T>
    // or foo<const T>
    foo(const foo<typename std::remove_const<T>::type> &) { }
};
```

Functionally, `foo` behaves similar to a `shared_ptr<T>`, with some other addon functionality that isn't relevant to this question. The semantics of the function dictate that it prefers to take in a `foo<const T>`. `foo<const T>` is implicitly constructible from `foo<T>`, so I would like to be able to do something like the following:

```
template <typename T>
void bar(foo<const T> f) { }

int main()
{
    bar(foo<const int>()); // fine
    bar(foo<int>());       // compile error
}
```

This fails because there are no matching overloads for `bar` that take a `foo<int>` (even though a `foo<const int>` could be implicitly constructed from a `foo<int>`, the overload resolution in concert with template instantiation seems to be stricter than that.

Is there a canonical way to accomplish this? I know that I could introduce a second overload for `bar()` that takes a `foo<T>` and dispatches manually to `bar(foo<const T>)`, but I'd like to avoid the duplication if possible.

Comment: Works fine for me as shown in my pre-C++11 compiler (bcc32), but not on ideone.com using C++14 (`types 'const T' and 'int' have incompatible cv-qualifiers`).

Comment: Is it just me or you did it vice versa? The copy c-tor uses `remove_const` and your description and the code that uses `bar` are about a case that **adds** `const`.

Comment: @YehezkelB.: The idea is that `foo<const T>` should be constructible from `foo<T>`, so you need to remove the `const` in the argument to the constructor. I *think* it's correct as written.

Comment: My mistake. You are right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you code doesn't work is because implicit conversion is apply after template argument deduction. So in that case, `foo<int>` indeed won't match `foo<const T>`, and the compiler won't able to deduce what the `T` is. You can try by yourself to check specify the type directly:

```
int main()
{
    bar(foo<const int>()); // fine
    bar<int>(foo<int>());  // also fine
}
```

What you can do is to let the compiler take any type:

```
template <typename T> // T might be foo<int>
void bar(T f) { }
```

Or if you want, you can let the compiler deduce the inner `T` without the const:

```
template <typename T> // can deduce T as const int
void bar(foo<T> f) { }
```

If you really want to enforce constness (even in generic code), you might want to add a utility function to your class, something like this:

```
foo<const T> as_const() const { return *this; }
```

So when you use a generic function, you can send is a const version of your class:

```
bar<int>(foo<int>{}.as_const());
```

Comment: It does turn out in the context where I'm invoking the template function, it is convenient to explicitly specify the template argument type, so that works for my application as well.

Comment: If you specify the template argument type, instead of cluttering your functions, you can define a template alias to retrieve what `T` your class foo was instantiated with.

Answer (score 6):

Templates don't allow for conversions!

When you write:

```
template <typename T>
void bar(foo<const T> f) { }
```

`bar` accepts a `foo<const T>`, for any `T`. It accepts nothing else. It doesn't matter that `foo<int>` is convertible to `foo<const int>`, that conversion is never considered. Full stop.

If you want to treat the received `f` as `const`, you can conditionally make it `const`:

```
// convert this version
template <class T> foo<T const> make_const_f(foo<T> const& rhs) { return {rhs}; }    
// pass this version through
template <class T> foo<T const>& make_const_f(foo<T const>& rhs) { return rhs; }

template <typename T>
void bar(foo<T> f) {
    auto&& const_f = make_const_f(f);

    // if T was const, const_f is a reference to f
    // if T wasn't const, const_f is a new object of type foo<T const>
}
```

Comment: With `as_const` being proposed for `std`, creating a free function with different semantics seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @Yakk Yeah, naming is hard.

Comment: There are two hard things in programming.  Naming, caching and off-by-one errors.